# first empty input field with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the first empty input field with a specific class (item_number)

below is not working

```
$("#pos_transaction_line_line input[value=''].item_number:first");
```

where as below works

```
$("#pos_transaction_line_line input.item_number").each(function(){
  if(!$(this).val()){
  //get the field here
  return false;
  }
});
```

After checking the code, I realized this is happening because the value of text field remains empty even after I enter some value in the text field.
So, my question is in what condition the value of text fields get populated after some one manaully enters the value in text field.

Second, is there is any other better way to get the field

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've discovered is that updating the value of the `<input>` updates its value `property` (`HTMLInputElement.value`), but not the `value` attribute (`<input value="...">`).

I'd suggest, though I'm unsure of any performance benefits, the following:

```
// selects the collection of elements represented by the selector,
// then filters that collection:
$("#pos_transaction_line_line input.item_number").filter(function(){
    // retains those <input>s the length of whose value property
    // is zero:
    return this.value.length === 0;
// then retrieves the first element (as a jQuery object still):
}).eq(0);
```

The above approach does suffer from the fact that it will, however, retrieve all elements matching the selector, and then loop through those elements in the `filter()` method, before returning the first-match in the page.

This does confer a performance penalty, but is presented as an alternative to use of the `each()` in the event that you may need to broaden the selection when faced with different circumstances and requirements.

References:

- [`eq()`](http://api.jquery.com/eq/).
- [`filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/).

Comment: I think what OP has is better because it skips the loop after finding the first blank element, using a filter will loop through all elements in the first set.

Comment: You're very welcome indeed; I'm glad to have provided some small help.

Answer (score 1):

That is the difference between attribute and property, the value attribute is used to set the initial value of the input element after that any changes done to the value will be updated in the value property. Initially the value of the `value` attribute will be copied to the `value` property thus giving the initial value of the input field.

The selector we are using here is the [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/), which does not see the changes done to the value property that is why this is happening.

Answer (score -1):

try this code using  [eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq/)

```
 if($('#pos_transaction_line_line input.item_number').eq(0).val() !== '');
```

Comment: I didn't down-vote this answer, but looking at it I think you've missed the point of the question.

Comment: you can see approved answer is using same thing which i mention in my answer but in other way ..